# Qt double from JSON precision

Tags: c++, json, qt, double

I receive a JSON Array from a server which looks like: [0.00015099, 1, -672.41163]
These values are orderbook entries. If I try to parse all values as double, my price differs slightly from the price in the JSON array. It is clear for me, that this happens because of the double conversion, but how to program around some crazy stuff like this?
Need these values also for calculation, compares etc.
I am using Qt5 and C++.

Any hint?

Comment: `double` is the worst choice to deal with money (unless you can _double_ it). Use fixed decimals and certain rounding rules instead, the bookkeepers will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use some Decimal type if you want to deal with money to be on a safe side. Unfortunately, Qt does not have decimal type for some reason. So, you may end up with some rounding rules/conventions **if you have no other choice**. Otherwise **you'd better** to implement your own implementation or use some existing solution like [qdecimal](https://github.com/semihc/qdecimal).